# is there a Multi-level query about odata

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to odata, I want to query the data of a specified index in a multi-level list. But I did not find a corresponding solution. This is my model.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And I have configure the odata in endpoints.

```
    IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customer");

        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

How can I show the correct index data in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no this rule to filter the index of data, but you can filter it through top and skip. top can help remove the previous indexes data, skip can remove the remaining indexes data. So this rule you can refer to.

```
https://localhost:44363/odata/Customer?$select=items($top=1;$skip=1)
```